# how do I register msgQEvStart() with a certain taskID

Tags: events, queue, task, fifo, vxworks

I would liek to assign `msgQEvStart()` to trigger an event in a certain task ID just like I can do with `eventSend()` but it doesn't provide an argument for it. How can I do this, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Only the calling task can register itself to be notified via events when a message arrives in a queue. (and only one task at a time can receive events for a particular message queue).

Comment: Yes, it is. Check out the documentation from within Workbench